# How to Construct This Small, Simple Electronic Device?

Tags: audio, power-electronics, wire, sound

I was fascinated to read of the small device depicted in this article: http://cornellsun.com/2017/11/10/hundreds-rickrolled-in-mysterious-campus-prank-at-cornell/

It is a very small device that can play a small number of notes, and do so at different intervals of time. The article describes it as "a quarter-sized black disc with several wires and a watch battery."

How can I build one of these things? I don't care if it looks the same, just that it has the same functionality. I would just want basic electronic tones; the ability to program it to go off at certain (hopefully somewhat random) times is also highly desired.

Comment: This is not a site for "please design this for me" type of questions. The gadget you refer to is likely a coin battery cell + a microcontroller (PIC10F200, TinyAVR, etc) + a small (maybe piezo) speaker. But that doesn't help you much if you can't program a microcontroller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go..........

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff11VC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: LOL I think you're taking the OP's words of "I don't care if it looks the same, just that it has the same functionality." for granted ;)

Answer (score 0):

For better sound lookup "30s Button Recordable Voice Module Music Box Sound Record For Plush Doll Toy Gift "